# How to add an id or a class to a form element in Drupal?

Tags: javascript, forms, drupal

What I'm trying to do is add an id to a hidden field, so that I can edit its value via JS. For example, I want to give the hidden element I create via a Drupal form with this:

```
$form['position'] = array(
'#type' => 'hidden',
'#default_value' => '57.149953,-2.104053',
);
```

Which outputs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="position" value="57.149953,-2.104053" />
```

Well I would like to add an id, a name and a class to that input. What's the best way to go around doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I actually just used "getElementsByName" instead. This works, however if anyone has a solution for adding an id attribute to the element that would be great!

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set attributes on a form element 
like this:

```
$form['position'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#default_value' => '57.149953,-2.104053',
  '#attributes' => array(
    'class' => 'a-class',
    'id' => 'an-id',
    'foo' => 'bar'
  )
);
```